# Using Boolean Wraps texture awkwardly

Tags: texturing, modifiers

I added textures to a minecraft character, but I realized I forgot the holes for the eyes. So I used a boolean modifier to make the holes, but it was unsuccessful. The holes appear except the texture wrap becomes messy and doesn't go around my character properly.

Without Boolean modifier
[image: Without Boolean]

With Boolean modifier
[image: With Boolean]

Comment: And here is the .blend http://www.mediafire.com/download/ad9vmmjcome7avg/Steve.blend

Comment: What are you hoping to do with the eye holes? Will you have separate eyeball objects that fit in the sockets and have their own texture?

Comment: Also, can you upload your character's texture so I can test with it?

Comment: 1. ) For the eyes ,  am going to make them a simple cube in the model so i can rig them for animation of course lol , They will NOT be seperate from the model . OH and the eyes will not use a texture , they will be using a coloured material

Comment: 2.) i will give you the textures now. http://www.mediafire.com/view/w8t0o7a6x3xg2ec/Steve.png

Comment: I don't understand how you are going to rig a rectangular cube to act as an eyeball...will the eye cube have an iris on it? If so, how will you move the eyes? If you rotate the cubes in any way, they will not be flush with the face of your character...is that ok?

Comment: Ok its hard to explain sorry , but let me explain the best i can , Soooo what im doing is making a hole with those 2 cubes to make the eye holes . then im going make the cubes ( NOT the holes ) smaller , and they are going to act as a iris . Its not going to have alot of detail . When i rig the iris , i am going to move them AWAY from the body and then apply the bones , then move them back so i can animate them , Does that make any sense at all . (sorry if it doesn't )

Comment: Oh, ok, I see now. I'll see what I can think of.

Comment: Well, if you cut holes for the eyes and then just add small cubes for irises, then you will have the iris cubes floating & then moving in empty eye sockets. Is that right? That might look weird, so what if you don't cut out the eye holes and then just have the iris cubes stick just BARELY out of the eyes and then animate them to move around in the eyes? Then most likely nobody would notice the irises are not absolutely flush with the eyes.

Comment: If i do that , i wont be able to make them all the way up without them touching the skin part of the texture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why your head object is acting so strangely with the Boolean modifier. The proper setting for the Boolean is "Intersect" in order to get the cubes to cut holes in the head:

[image]

However, I don't know why the body disappears. So, here is a work-around:

1. First, delete the back vertices of the cubes you're going to use to cut out the eye holes so they are just rectangles, like this:

   [image]
2. Then go into Front Ortho view (front view with <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>, ortho view with <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>):

   [image]
3. Now first select the rectangles, then hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and also select the player, so that both are selected together.
4. Now, press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to go into Edit mode, then in the Tools panel, in the Tools tab, click on Knife Project:

   [image]

   This will cut holes in the face of the player.
5. Now select the vertices of the newly-made eye sockets and extrude them back along the Y axis:

   [image]
6. Now select the back-most vertices of one eye socket and then press <kbd>F</kbd> to make a face there. Then do the same thing for the other eye socket:

   [image]