# UV Maps not preserved after Boolean Modifier

Tags: modifiers, uv

I have multiple objects I need to boolean together, but when I apply the modifier, the UV maps get messed up in a very odd manner. It is actually visible before the modifier is applied.

Two Objects:

[image]

Before Application:

[image]

UV Map afterwards:

[image]

I can't for the life of me figure out what the problem is. I checked the face normals, made sure the meshes were manifold and applied all materials to the objects in multiple configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at this , I have had the same problem : [Using Boolean Wraps texture awkwardly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8168/using-boolean-wraps-texture-awkwardly)

they answered by saying i have to use the "Knife tool" Or knife project . The boolean should heavily be avoided , especially when you have already textured your mesh because it adds un necessary edges , doubles and vertices .

Comment: Thanks, that worked out just fine. The odd thing about this model is that it is the first model I've had this problem with. I've textured objects and booleaned them together before without any hitches.

Comment: Update: So, I kept a copy of the objects without the knife tool. I found that merging the objects then separating them again fixes the problem.